# Find the weakest link

Tags: riddle, pattern

This is a linking puzzle with a weak link. The links should form a circle connecting consecutive items and in the end connecting items 1 and 7 as well:

> 1. A person with the same lastname as a doctor in the Bible.
>      [Hint: Graffiti]
>
> 1.-2. A fictional master of the whip.
>
> 2. A meteorological phenomenon.
>
> 2.-3. A time of the year.
>
> 3. The Norwegian translation of one of the most common formulas in Excel.
>
> 3.-4. A fascinating love story.
>
> 4. The ship of the egg master.
>
> 4.-5. Clue 4 and 5 share their firstnames.
>
> 5. A German suicide bomber.
>
> 5.-6. An actor with the lastname of a vacation activity. [Hint: tomgun]
>
> 6. The lastname of the founder of a religious science.
>
> 6.-7. Similarity in names.
>
> 7. A binocular.
>
> 7.-1. Looking at differences and quarrels with the binocular.

**But there is a weak link here.

Which of the links is so weak that it can't hold the puzzle together?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chain breaks between items 3 and 4.
Hence, I start my solution with the weak link 3-4, followed by all remaining items and links in increasing order up to the final item 3.

3.-4. A fascinating love story.

> West Side Story with Tony and MARIA

4. The ship of the egg master.

   > SANTA MARIA (one of the ships of Christopher Columbus; egg of Columbus)

4.-5. Clue 4 and 5 share their firstnames.

> SANTA CLAUS

5. A German suicide bomber.

   > CLAUS von Stauffenberg (who tried to assassinate Hitler in July 1944 by planting a bomb)

5.-6. An actor with the lastname of a vacation activity.

> Tom CRUISE (who played Stauffenberg in a recent movie; also played in "Top Gun" which might sound vaguely similar to the "tomgun" in the hint)

6. The lastname of the founder of a religious science.

   > Ron HUBBARD (founder of Scientology Church; Tom Cruise is a member of Scientology)

6.-7. Similarity in names.

> HUBBARD and HUBBLE start with the first four (uncommon) letters

7. A binocular.

   > The HUBBLE telescope

7.-1. Looking at differences and quarrels with the binocular.

> Star wars (created by George Lucas)

1. A person with the same lastname as a doctor in the Bible.

   > George Lucas (Colossians 4:14: Luke the beloved physician and Demas greet you; also director of "American Graffiti" and hence fits with the hint "graffiti")

1.-2. A fictional master of the whip.

> INDIANA Jones (created by George Lucas and Steven Spielberg)

2. A meteorological phenomenon.

   > INDIAN SUMMER

2.-3. A time of the year.

> SUMMER

3. The Norwegian translation of one of the most common formulas in Excel.

   > SUMMERING (Norwegian for the excel command SUM)

Comment: 3.-4. Is just humbug, and therefore the weak link

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit lame but here is my progress:

Hint 1 - Luke

Hint 1-2 - Luke Taylor

Hint 4 - Fritz Hansen

Hint 5 - Fritz X

Comment: Why is Fritz Hansen the egg master?